# How to add Subtitle with Video in Apple TV

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am working on Apple TV application. I have one URL of Video and one URL of video Subtitle.
I want to play video with subtitle. Anybody have a solution for this problem

If you have please let me know.

There is a Video URL: "https://sample/hls_playlist.m3u8"

There is a Subtitle URL: "https://samplesubtitle=AKIAJS5BLYTDP3J5UOFQ&Expires=1507918258&Signature=r%2FcV7UVSejOBYDKFHwMYtrvXUmM%3D"

This is my code:

```
 func playVideo(_ videoURL: String) {

    // 1 - Load video asset

    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: URL(string:videoURL)!) as AVURLAsset

    // 2 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition.init()

    // 3 - Video track
    let videoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    try? videoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: (videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]), at: kCMTimeZero)

    // 4 - Subtitle track
    let subtitleAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: URL(string: self.subtitle!)!)
    let subtitleTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeText, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    try? subtitleTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: subtitleAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeText)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)




    self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(asset: mixComposition)
    self.playerObj = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: self.playerItem)
    self.playerController?.player = self.playerObj

    self.playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: Notification.Name.status.rawValue, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
    self.playerController?.player!.play()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PlayerViewController.playerItemDidReachEnd(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerObj.currentItem)
}
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340247/adding-text-subtitles-to-video-track-in-swift-fails-with-error-code-11841